# Mapping IP to latitude and longitude by MaxMind database

Tags: geolocation, maxmind

I want to map a bunch of IP addresses to their latitude and longitude by MaxMind database. My code is in C, I do not know how to use this database.

Comment: I tried the following code and got this error:   /tmp/ccZD5Cwa.o: In function main': geo.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to GeoIP_open' geo.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `GeoIP_record_by_name' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something along these lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GeoIP.h>
#include <GeoIPCity.h>

int main()
{
    GeoIP *gi;
    GeoIPRecord *gir;

    gi = GeoIP_open("/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat", GEOIP_INDEX_CACHE);

    if (gi == NULL) {
        /* handle error */
    }

    gir = GeoIP_record_by_name(gi, "1.1.1.1");
    if (gir == NULL) {
        /* handle error */
    }

    printf("latitude: %f   longitude: %f", gir->latitude, gir->longitude);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I run this code I get an error like:
/tmp/ccZD5Cwa.o: In function `main':
geo.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `GeoIP_open'
geo.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `GeoIP_record_by_name'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did you link against libGeoIP, e.g., `gcc geo.c -lGeoIP -o geo`? That said, you might want to consider using a higher level language such as Python or Perl.